# Extract Id's from String with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to extract the Id's from the following string via SQL (no T-SQL)

```
XY_FOO_BAR1=123;XY_FOO_BAR2=456;XY_FOO_BAR3=789;
```

The result should look like this:

```
123
456
789
```

With T-SQL it would be easy but how can I solve the problem with pure SQL? I have already tried a few things with `PATINDEX`, `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` but unfortunately this is quite complicated and it is certainly easier to implement.

I would be grateful for any tips.

**final solution thanks @mtdot:**

```
with List as (
    select v.value as keyValue
      from xy.foo cross apply STRING_SPLIT(stay_val,';') as v
     where id = 987654321 
)
select (select value from STRING_SPLIT(KeyValue, '=') order by value desc offset 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only) as Ids from List
```

Comment: What do you mean by no T-SQL? T-SQL is SQL Servers dialect of SQL, and as such `PATINDEX` (for example) is T-SQL... its not ANSII SQL.

Comment: This is, in truth, something for your ETL process to do *before* it `INSERT`s the data into your database. T-SQL's strength is not string manipulation, far from it in fact. Hopefully what ever ETL process you are using is better at it.

Comment: Did you try to use regex?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex, @UmutTEKİN . Not without CLR objects at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried with this and seems ok.
But `order by value` seems tricky

```
declare @Raw nvarchar(max) = 'XY_FOO_BAR1=123;XY_FOO_BAR2=456;XY_FOO_BAR3=789;';
with List as (
    select value as KeyValue from STRING_SPLIT(@Raw, ';') where value != ''
)
select (select value from STRING_SPLIT(KeyValue, '=') order by value desc offset 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only) as Ids from List
```

Comment: Are you sure that isn't T-SQL? ;)

Comment: @mtdot : Your approach + cross apply is my solution. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Tim If this satisfies your question, then please mark it as the answer to both close it and to help others find useful "answers" in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help

=======

```
 declare @a varchar(100);
set @a = 'XY_FOO_BAR1=123;XY_FOO_BAR2=456;XY_FOO_BAR3=789;';
;with split1(whole) as
(
    select value from string_split(@a,';') where value <> ''
)
SELECT (select value from String_split(whole, '=') order by value desc offset 1 rows)  FROM  split1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).